# Skip comileJava and processResources task in gradle for Kotlin deployment

Tags: gradle, kotlin

When I deploy my kotlin project, the build depends on the classes task. 
The problem I have with it is, that classes invokes compileJava and it always fails with **"NO-SOURCE"** error. Of course I don't have java sources, it is a Kotlin-only project.

How can I skip the compileJava task in my build chain?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you say the tasks fail when they only report `NO-SOURCE`. As can be seen in your screenshot, despite the `NO-SOURCE`, Gradle still reports `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

But of course, you can also skip these irrelevant tasks (which will make Gradle report them as `SKIPPED` instead of `NO-SOURCE`):

```
compileJava {
    enabled = false
}
```